# Call Slot of different class

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I want to execute the slot of different class. When i execute this code its compiling without any error but not getting Output

```
pendrive1::pendrive1()
{
    UI_CDBurn Obj; 
connect( Obj.penDrive, SIGNAL(clicked()),&Obj , SLOT(caller()));
}
```

Here my slot is not working. Slot in UI_CDBurn is public. But when i called with a button in pendrive1 class its working fine

```
UI_CDBurn *Obj=new UI_CDBurn; 
connect( ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),Obj , SLOT( caller())); // Working File
```

Comment: Hey, please post your code in some sample example.. it helps to analyse.. or write your question in descriptive manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, What is pendrive? It must be a pointer to a QObject derived class with a signal named `clicked`.

I guess you have declared the `clicked` signal in the [pendrive] class but is the signal emitted? When the user click you need to emit the `clicked` signal with the following instruction:

```
emit clicked();
```

You can find how to use custom signals and slots here: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/signalsandslots.html.

Comment: Clicked() slot is of Obj class